# SQL Recursive CTE - Recursive member of a common table expression 'CTE' has multiple recursive references

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to be able to "look back" during the execution of a CTE. Using the sample data below I need an additional column returned which represents the balance as of the BalanceDate column. So rowid 6 would return 30 because that is the balance as of 3/6/2015. Rowid 9 would return 80 because that is the last record closest to 9/30/2015. When I try to use the CTE as a derived table I receive the error

> Msg 253, Level 16, State 1, Procedure 
>   Recursive member of a common table expression 'CTE' has multiple recursive references.

```
--Sample data
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(RowID int null,
 TranDate date null,
 Amount int null,
 BalanceDate date null);


 INSERT INTO #TEMP (RowID,TranDate, Amount, BalanceDate)
 SELECT 1,'1/15/2015',10,null
UNION ALL
 SELECT 2,'2/18/2015',10,null
UNION ALL
 SELECT 3,'3/6/2015',10,null
UNION ALL
 SELECT 4,'6/1/2015',10,null
UNION ALL
 SELECT 5,'6/18/2015',10,null
UNION ALL
 SELECT 6,'7/31/2015',10,'3/6/2015'
UNION ALL
 SELECT 7,'8/2/2015',10,null
UNION ALL
 SELECT 8,'9/13/2015',10,null
UNION ALL
 SELECT 9,'11/15/2015',10,'9/30/2015';

with CTE  
as  
( SELECT RowID, TranDate, Amount, Balance=Amount, BalanceDate FROM #TEMP WHERE RowID = 1
 UNION ALL
  SELECT #TEMP.RowID,#TEMP.TranDate, #TEMP.Amount, Balance = #TEMP.Amount + CTE.Balance, #TEMP.BalanceDate
  FROM #TEMP
  INNER JOIN CTE on #Temp.RowID = CTE.RowID + 1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a running sum up to a particular date. Could you clarify the calculation you're trying to perform. It may that a correlated subquery is appropriate. Asides: Are all transaction `Amount` values >= 0, or are there negative amounts? Any time I see something like `#Temp.RowID = CTE.RowID + 1` I wonder what happens when an `Id` is missing due to a deleted row, rolled back transaction, ... .

Comment: I don't want a running total, I want the balance as of a certain date. So for example if the row has a BalanceDate of 9/30/2015 I want the closest record to that date but not greater than that date (9/30/2015). In my case the data is being populated into a temp table with an identity column so no rowid's will be missing. Thanks

Comment: What should the balance be for the rows that have NULL for balance date?

Comment: Those can be null as there is no computation required for those rows.

Answer (score 0):

I generally avoid recursive CTEs unless there's a reason you need to use them (for example, to find parents and children). Rather than using a recursive CTE, you can do something like this to get what you want:

EDIT:

If there are ever negative amounts, this would produce the correct result.

```
SELECT RowID, T1.TranDate, Amount 
    , (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM #TEMP WHERE TranDate <= T1.TranDate) Balance
    , BalanceDate
    , (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM #TEMP WHERE TranDate <= T1.BalanceDate) BalanceToDate
FROM #TEMP T1
```

Edited out other queries that were here before to make this less messy.

Using original recursive CTE:

```
; WITH CTE AS  
( 
    SELECT RowID, TranDate, Amount, Balance=Amount, BalanceDate 
    FROM TEMP 
    WHERE RowID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TEMP.RowID,TEMP.TranDate, TEMP.Amount, Balance = TEMP.Amount + CTE.Balance, TEMP.BalanceDate
    FROM TEMP
    JOIN CTE on Temp.RowID = CTE.RowID + 1
)
SELECT C.RowID, C.TranDate, C.Amount, C.Balance, C.BalanceDate
    , (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM CTE WHERE TranDate <= C.BalanceDate) BalanceToDate
FROM CTE C
```

Comment: Are you assuming that all transactions have a non-negative `Amount`, i.e. that `MAX` will return the most recent value in a date range?

Comment: @HABO I was assuming that, yes. Edited in another answer to reflect the possibility of negative amounts.

Comment: Due to other conditions and calculations in my current CTE, I need to be able to keep this as part of my existing CTE. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Rolando Um... The recursive part of a recursive CTE can't really do that. You shouldn't be using a recursive CTE for that. What you can do is put the answer in another CTE and select from there as necessary, or with your current recursive CTE, do a select statement like the one I just edited in.